# SQL: SUM the COUNT and GROUP to Combine Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, sum

Is there a was to combine these two queries into one query, so that the result is:

```
ChannelId   | ContentType | ContentTypeCount | SumOfAllContentTypes
  100       | link        | 59               | 179
  100       | photo       | 49               | 179
  100       | status      | 2                | 179
  100       | video       | 4                | 179
  101       | link        | 15               | 179
  101       | status      | 50               | 179
```

Here are the queries I'm using currently:

```
SELECT
COUNT(posts.id)
FROM posts
INNER JOIN channels ON channels.id = posts.channel_id
WHERE channels.site_id = 1003
AND channels.channel_type_id = 1
```

result = 179

and..

```
SELECT
posts.channel_id,
posts.contenttype,
COUNT(posts.contenttype) as contenttypecount
FROM posts
INNER JOIN channels ON channels.id = posts.channel_id
WHERE channels.site_id = 1003
AND channels.channel_type_id = 1
GROUP BY posts.channel_id, posts.contenttype
```

result = 100 | link | 59; etc..

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: probably, but why would you want to? both queries are using different conditions that don't apply to each other. it'd be like wanting having an apple and orange, and demanding they be combined into an orple.

Comment: You can just `JOIN posts` again, but _why_ would you stress the database out for something you can clearly get already?

Comment: @MarcB: Should we really judge the Business Requirments stated by the OP?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: **Clarifying** (not judging) the **business** requirements may enable those requirements to be met using different **technical** means than those envisaged by the OP.

Comment: @MarkBannister: That's good, but you may be coming across a bit stronger than you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select A.*, B.*
from (
  SELECT
  posts.channel_id,
  posts.contenttype,
  COUNT(posts.contenttype) as contenttypecount
  FROM posts
  INNER JOIN channels ON channels.id = posts.channel_id
  WHERE channels.site_id = 1003
  AND channels.channel_type_id = 1
  GROUP BY posts.channel_id, posts.contenttype
) A
join (
  SELECT
  COUNT(posts.id) as Total
  FROM posts
  INNER JOIN channels ON channels.id = posts.channel_id
  WHERE channels.site_id = 1003
  AND channels.channel_type_id = 1
) B on 1=1
```

Not particularly efficient, but easy and simple.

Comment: Thank you kindly Pieter. That query works and returns the results in  0.0027 sec.